# When was “the Most Holy Place” anointed, as foretold at Daniel 9:24?

Tags: prophecy, daniel

Daniel 9:24 NASB

> 24 “Seventy [a]weeks have been decreed for your people and your holy
> city, to [b]finish the wrongdoing, to [c]make an end of sin, to make
> atonement for guilt, to bring in everlasting righteousness, to seal up
> vision and prophecy, and ***to anoint the Most Holy Place.***

Comment: Daniel 9:24 does not foretell anything; it simply warns that 490 years (spanning from the first year of [Darius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darius_II) [423 BC], mentioned in 9:1, until the [destruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Jerusalem_(70_CE)) of the [Second Temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Temple), in AD 70) have graciously been given by God to the Jews to meet or fulfill a list of demands; in the Greek Septuagint, 9:26 reads *anointing* instead of *anointed*, referring to the cessation of the anointing of priests, coinciding with the siege of Jerusalem.

Comment: Are you asking about the anointing of the Messiah (God’s anointed one) or the anointing of the  Most Holy, the Sanctuary?  If the latter, do you mean the Most Holy in heaven (given the Temple in Jerusalem was destroyed in 70 A.D.)?  Your question suggests this has already happened.  A bit more clarity would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not so fast - the word "place" does not appear in the Hebrew text - the Hebrew only says, "anoint most holy".  Further, another five things were to occur as well.

Notice that from the beginning of Daniel’s prayer in Dan 9, Daniel is concerned for (a) the “desolation of Jerusalem” (V2), and, (b) the people of the covenant who have been unfaithful (V4-6).  This is again summarised in V19 where Daniel pleads: “O Lord, listen! O Lord, forgive! O Lord, hear and act! For Your sake, O my God, do not delay, because Your city and Your people bear Your name.”  It will be seen shortly, that two-fold purpose of the Daniel’s confessional prayer is answered with a two-fold response involving the city and the people of the covenant.

Let us begin with the literary structure of the passage.

**Literary Structure**

A simplified literary structure of Dan 9:24-27 looks something like this:

70 weeks are determined for

A: Your people [2 word phrase]

. B:  Your Holy City [3 word phrase]

A: Finish the-transgression, end sin, expiate iniquity [2 word phrases]

. B: Introduce eternal righteousness, seal vision & prophecy, anoint most holy [3 word phrases]

A: From the decree to restore and rebuild Jerusalem till Messiah – 7 weeks + 62 weeks

. B: Rebuilt in times of trouble

A: After 62 weeks Messiah cut off and will have nothing

. B: People of prince destroy city & sanctuary, end like a flood, war & desolations

A: He confirms covenant with many for 1 week, cut off mid-week & stops sacrifice & offering

. B: On the wing will come abomination that makes desolate until the end

Without getting into a detailed exposition of this Messianic prophecy, anointing the most holy refers to anointing Messiah, ie, at His baptism which initiated His earthly ministry, as per Luke 3.

Comment: Dottard @  you are correct,at the time of Jesus’ baptism, God’s heavenly abode was anointed, or set apart, as “the Most Holy ” in the great spiritual temple arrangement. Accepted as correct, Tks

Answer (score 2):

The Hebrew word "נֶחְתַּ֥ךְ" (neḥ·taḵ), translated as "decreed" in the NASB, means to be determined, be settled, be marked out. However, we look for a decree to indicate the start of the time period based on the following verse:

> Know therefore and understand, that **from the going forth of the
> commandment to restore and to build Jerusalem** unto the Messiah the
> Prince shall be seven weeks, and threescore and two weeks: the street
> shall be built again, and the wall, even in troublous times. (Daniel
> 9:25)

That commandment, recorded in Ezra 7, was most fully given by Artaxerxes in his seventh year (vs. 7).  The command broadly applied to the rebuilding of Jerusalem, but especially was the temple's rebuilding a focus of this commandment.

> Whatsoever is commanded by the God of heaven, let it be diligently
> done for the house of the God of heaven: for why should there be wrath
> against the realm of the king and his sons? (Ezra 7:23)

Because the reign of Artaxerxes is well established in history, the date of this proclamation is known to have been in 457 B.C.  However, if we understand the prophecy, we can calculate back to that date ourselves from its endpoint.

Prophetic years in the Bible were represented by days.  The book of Daniel was written in multiple languages, but this part is actually Hebrew, and in Hebrew the word for "day" ("יוֹם", yowm) could also mean "time" or "year."  So it was natural for the Hebrew mindset to link the concepts of day and year.  And God used this parallelism to apply His prophetic times, where He appoints a day to represent a year.

> After the number of the days in which ye searched the land, even forty
> days, each day for a year, shall ye bear your iniquities, even forty
> years, and ye shall know my breach of promise. (Numbers 14:34)
>
> For I have laid upon thee the years of their iniquity, according to
> the number of the days, three hundred and ninety days: so shalt thou
> bear the iniquity of the house of Israel. And when thou hast
> accomplished them, lie again on thy right side, and thou shalt bear
> the iniquity of the house of Judah forty days: I have appointed thee
> each day for a year. (Ezekiel 4:5-6)

These verses demonstrate the Biblical day-for-year principle that is used in prophecy, and in Revelation parallel times are given showing the same principle.  When we apply this to the prophecy given in Daniel 9, the math is simple.

70 weeks = 490 days --> 490 years

But the last week is "cut off" from this time period, or set apart.

> Know therefore and understand, that from the going forth of the
> commandment to restore and to build Jerusalem unto the Messiah the
> Prince shall be **seven weeks, and threescore and two weeks:** the street
> shall be built again, and the wall, even in troublous times.
> And after threescore and two weeks shall Messiah be cut off, but not
> for himself: and the people of the prince that shall come shall
> destroy the city and the sanctuary; and the end thereof shall be with
> a flood, and unto the end of the war desolations are determined. (vss.
> 25-26)

Seven weeks and threescore and two weeks = 69 weeks

(Remember that a score is 20.)

69 weeks = 483 days --> 483 years

From the time of the commandment to the coming of the Messiah was to be 483 years.  In the midst of that last week (see vs. 27, below) that is set apart from the the others (70 - 1 = 69), the Messiah is to be "cut off."  That's a Hebrew euphemism for being killed.

> And he shall confirm the covenant with many for **one week:** and **in
> the midst of the week he shall cause the sacrifice and the oblation to
> cease,** and for the overspreading of abominations he shall make it
> desolate, even until the consummation, and that determined shall be
> poured upon the desolate. (Daniel 9:27)

When Jesus was crucified, that ended the law of sacrifices.  The veil in the temple was supernaturally rent, top to bottom, to indicate this, as described in the gospels.

> And, behold, the veil of the temple was rent in twain from the top to
> the bottom; and the earth did quake, and the rocks rent; (Matthew
> 27:51)
>
> And the veil of the temple was rent in twain from the top to the
> bottom. (Mark 15:38)
>
> And the sun was darkened, and the veil of the temple was rent in the
> midst. (Luke 23:45)

This was prophesied to occur "in the midst of the week."  Since one week represents seven years of time, the middle of the week would have three and a half years to either side.  Jesus ministered for three and a half years.  Following this, there were yet three and a half years' time granted to the Jews until A.D. 34 when the gospel went from them to the Gentiles, as marked by their rejection of it at the stoning of Stephen.

As I understand the prophecy, it was Christ's atonement, Christ's blood, which "anointed" the Most Holy Place.

Answer (score 2):

**Daniel 9:24** שבעים שבעים נחתך על עמך ועל עיר קדשך לכלא הפשע ולחתם חטאות ולכפר עון ולהביא צדק עלמים ולחתם חזון ונביא **ולמשח קדש קדשים**׃

And **to anoint the Most Holy**, **קדש קדשים kodesh kodashim, "the Holy of holies." משח mashach, to anoint**. Commentary's are divided if this was a future event to be taken literally (e.g Millenium era) or to be taken spiritually.

The arc of the covenant which without their is no holy of holies was lost/hidden at the Babylonian invasion, the same time as prophet Daniel was taken to Babylon. When he write this the arc is gone and their is no holy of holies, the question is what did Daniel see in his vision given from God?

---

**First Advent fulfilment;**

The majority shear the **spiritual** aspect that through the cross, Christ finished the transgression of His people Israel and made an end to sin.

> **He Himself is the atoning sacrifice for our sins**, and not only for
> ours but also for the sins of the whole world. **(1 John 2:2 - Berean Study
> Bible)**

> **In Him we have redemption through His blood**, the forgiveness of our trespasses, according to the riches of His grace. **(Eph 1:7 - BSB)**

Ron Wyatt even dear to claim, that at the crucifixion the blood of Jesus poured down trough a crack in the mountain that occurred when the earth was shaken, and atoned the arc, that was hidden below him Golgotha. [Ron Wyatt - The Ark of the Covenant](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7UyqxzuSMCo&t=309s)

> 50 When Jesus had cried out again in a loud voice, He yielded up His
> spirit. 51 At that moment the veil of the temple was torn in two from
> top to bottom. **The earth quaked and the rocks were split**. 52 The tombs
> broke open, and the bodies of many saints who had fallen asleep were
> raised. **(Matthew 27:50-52 - BSB)**

> Instead, one of the soldiers pierced His side with a spear, and
> immediately **blood and water flowed out**. **(John 19:34 - BSB)**

---

**Second Advent fulfilment;**

A minority believe in a **literally** fulfilment of the atoning in the Holy of holies, Those lean to a millenium fulminant of Daniel 9:24 from to Ezekiel 40-48 (see also; Isaiah 56:7, 66:20-​23, Zechariah 14:16-21).

17 It shall be the prince's duty to furnish the burnt offerings, grain offerings, and drink offerings, at the feasts, the new moons, and the Sabbaths, all the appointed feasts of the house of Israel: he shall provide the sin offerings, grain offerings, burnt offerings, and peace offerings, **to make atonement (H3722) on behalf of the house of Israel**. 18 “Thus says the Lord God: In the first month, on the first day of the month, you shall take a bull from the herd without blemish, and purify the sanctuary. 19 The priest shall take some of the blood of the sin offering and put it on the doorposts of the temple, the four corners of the ledge of the altar, and the posts of the gate of the inner court. 20 You shall do the same on the seventh day of the month for anyone who has sinned through error or ignorance; so you **shall make atonement (H3722) for the temple**. **(Ezekiel 45:17-20 - ESV)**

(H3722) כָּפַר kāp̄ar - to cover, purge, make an atonement, make reconciliation

and that through His Second Advent, the millennial rule and eternal kingdom that Christ will bring in everlasting righteousness and will one day finally deliver up the kingdom to God the Father, after having destroyed every rule; authority; principality and power.

1. To finish the transgression
2. To make an end of sin
3. To make atonement for iniquity
4. To bring in everlasting righteousness
5. To seal up vision and prophecy
6. To anoint the holy of holies

Comment: Jesus did not anoint the ark with his blood that's blasphemy, the priest shall thake oil to anoint the ark Leviticus 14:16

Comment: @KevinPopov Lev 14:14 He is to take some of the bull’s blood and with his finger sprinkle it on the front of the atonement cover;

Comment: 1st Jesus was not a bull but as a lamb 2nd its anoint no aton on the ark!!

Comment: Leviticus 16:32-34 The anointed priest is makes atonement for the holy of holies. Either its referring to the lit place or can be the person Jesus that fulfilled them all 6 on the cross with or without the ark beneath (if the ark was beneath, it would just be amazing). However the 2nd Temple had no Holy of holies or rather it was dark and empty behind the curtains.  It can also be that the holy of holies anointing occurred at His bap­tism. Its hard to fit Jesus live to Levitical law but one thing is clear no anointing no atoning.

Comment: OK how then is it even possible to be a second coming fulfilment?

Comment: @KevinPopov To finish the transgression, to make an end of sin, to make atonement for iniquity, to bring in everlasting righteousness, to seal up vision and prophecy, to anoint the holy of holies all this in v24 has to happen before the Seventy weeks ended. Messiah is cut of after 7 + 62 (69 weeks). it depends on who "he" is in v27 is either we are half in the 70th week (or mid 70th week has dubble fulfilment) or it has not started yet.

Answer (score 0):

The destruction of the Temple in AD 70 is prophesied in Dan. 9:24-27 and Mt. 24/Lk. 21.  When the physical old covenant temple was destroyed in AD 70 a new covenant spiritual Most Holy Place one would be complete and replace it.  We see that in Rev. 21:16 having come down to earth at the “soon” coming of Christ in AD 70 (Rev. 21:16–22:7, 10, 20).  The MHP New Jerusalem is also the Bride that is anointed on the wedding.  That’s how I exegetes this in my book, “Armageddon Deception….”  Hope that helps.

But AD 70 was also the time that the office of prophet would be stopped, so if it is referring to the OC priesthood stopping at that point - that makes sense as well.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/49338)